# Displaying API calls from nodeJS inside reactJS component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

so I'm making an app where I had to create a nodeJS server and I have to display the API calls on the client side(reactJS). However, when I call the fetch() method, nothing gets displayed on the client side but only on the server side in my terminal. I probably don't know how to do it properly, so I was just wondering if any of you guys have an idea of what I'm doing wrong, I just want to learn, that's all. Here's small part of my server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var key = "v2xcfdfa76db9f173028d97859c47a8ce0554321029a3fbfc06a26f81b1655bd3d9";
var BitGo = require('bitgo');
var client = new BitGo.BitGo({ env: 'test', accessToken: key });

router.get('/user/me', (req, res, next) => {
client.me({}, function callback(err, user) {
  if (err) {
  console.dir(err);
}
console.dir(user);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here's the client side:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  data: ""
    }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
 return fetch('/user/me')
.then((response)=> response.json())
.then((responseJson)=>{
  this.setState({
    data: responseJson.data
  });
})
 }
  render() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
    </header>
    <p className="App-intro">
      Data from our API: <b>{this.state.data}</b>
    </p>
  </div>
   );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you getting an error? If you getting an error please share.

Comment: What happens when you do:
```.then((response)=> {console.log(response) return response.json())}
```
What gets displayed in `response`? Please do the same with `responseJson`

Comment: @DrunkDevKek Hey, I tried doing the exact same thing you posted, but I cannot see the output of the console.log inside my browser...

Comment: @DrunkDevKek 'response' is not defined  no-undef. This is what I get if I print it at the end of my componentDidMount method.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually returning anything from the server... or so it seems with the limited code you gave us.

```
router.get('/user/me', (req, res, next) => {
  client.me({}, function callback(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.dir(err);
      res.status(400).send(err)
    }

    console.dir(user);
    res.send({ data: user })
  });
});
```

I'm assuming that `user` is JSON serializable (and that it's the data that you want returned from the server).

Comment: Hey, you are exactly right. I want user returned from the server. However I just tried using the code you provided and nothing has changed on the client side.

Comment: I've updated my code. You're pulling from `responseJson.data`, so I adjusted the response to put `user` into `data`.

Comment: I think we're getting close, so I've just got an error saying: Objects are not valid as a React child. this.setState({
    data: responseJson.data
  }); I believe the problem is here

Comment: well... sure. so `user` is an object... change `Data from our API: <b>{this.state.data}</b>` to pull out the data you want (i.e. `{this.state.data.name}` if `user` has a `name` property.

Comment: Tyler, if you ever end up in Copenhagen, send me a message because you're getting a big big drink from me. Thank you very much for explaining everything and helping me, appreciate it! :)

Comment: Sure, see you next week! ;)